# How to get evaluation result during training convolutional neural network (cnn) using tensorflow

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

I use TensorFlow to build super-resolution convolutional neural network for enhancing image resolution. The network accepts a low-resolution image as input and produces a high-resolution image as output.

For training, I use [tf.estimator.Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/estimators)

```
def get_estimator(run_config=None, params=None):
    """Return the model as a Tensorflow Estimator object.
    Args:
         run_config (RunConfig): Configuration for Estimator run.
         params (HParams): hyperparameters.
    """
    return tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=model_fn,  # First-class function
        params=params,  # HParams
        config=run_config  # RunConfig
    )
```

wrapped by [tf.contrib.learn.Experiment](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment)

```
def experiment_fn(run_config, params):
    """Create an experiment to train and evaluate the model.
    Args:
        run_config (RunConfig): Configuration for Estimator run.
        params (HParam): Hyperparameters
    Returns:
        (Experiment) Experiment for training the mnist model.
    """
    # You can change a subset of the run_config properties as
    run_config = run_config.replace(save_checkpoints_steps=params.min_eval_frequency)
    estimator = get_estimator(run_config, params)
    # # Setup data loaders
    train_input_fn = get_input_fn(params.filenames, params.epoch, True, params.batch_size)
    eval_input_fn = get_input_fn(params.filenames, 1, False, params.batch_size)

    # Define the experiment
    experiment = tf.contrib.learn.Experiment(
        estimator=estimator,  # Estimator
        train_input_fn=train_input_fn,  # First-class function
        eval_input_fn=eval_input_fn,  # First-class function
        train_steps=params.train_steps,  # Minibatch steps
        min_eval_frequency=params.min_eval_frequency,  # Eval frequency
        eval_steps=params.eval_steps  # Minibatch steps
    )
    return experiment
```

And I run it via [tf.contrib.learn.learn_runner](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/learn_runner) as follow:

```
def run_experiment(config, session):
    assert os.path.exists(config.tfrecord_dir)
    assert os.path.exists(os.path.join(config.tfrecord_dir, config.dataset, config.subset))


    save_config(config.summaries_dir, config)

    filenames = get_tfrecord_files(config)
    batch_number = min(len(filenames), config.train_size) // config.batch_size
    logging.info('Total number of batches  %d' % batch_number)

    params = tf.contrib.training.HParams(
        learning_rate=config.learning_rate,
        device=config.device,
        epoch=config.epoch,
        batch_size=config.batch_size,
        min_eval_frequency=100,
        train_steps=None,  # Use train feeder until its empty
        eval_steps=1,  # Use 1 step of evaluation feeder
        filenames=filenames
    )
    run_config = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(model_dir=config.checkpoint_dir)

    learn_runner.run(
        experiment_fn=experiment_fn,  # First-class function
        run_config=run_config,  # RunConfig
        schedule="train_and_evaluate",  # What to run
        hparams=params  # HParams
    )
```

The class Experiment provides method train_and_evaluate that evaluate during training.

**My question is**: *How can I get an evaluation result(an output image) during training cnn?* I want to see a temporal training result.

My project on [github](https://github.com/datbui/enhancer)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for adding an image summary to your model using [`tf.summary.image`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/image).

It makes it easy to visualize images during training in Tensorboard:

```py
def model_fn(...):
    ...
    # max_outputs control the number of images in the batch you want to display
    tf.summary.image("train_images", images, max_outputs=3)
    # ...
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(...)
```

---

During evaluation, I don't think there is an easy way to display an image inside `tf.estimator`. The issue is that during evaluation, only integer or float values can be displayed.

In more details, at eval time you return `eval_metric_ops` containing for instance your accuracy. TensorFlow will display every integer or float value from this dict in TensorBoard, but will give you a warning if you try to display anything else (ex: images). (Source code: function [`_write_dict_to_summary`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py#L973))

> WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping summary for eval_images, must be a float, np.float32, np.int64, np.int32 or int.

A workaround could be to get back the value of the images outside of `tf.estimator` and display them manually in TensorBoard.

---

**Edit**: there is another related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852018/tensorflow-estimator-api-save-image-summary-in-eval-mode) on stackoverflow, and two GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14042) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15332) to track progress on this.
From what I understand, they will try to make it easy to return an image summary in `eval_metric_ops` that will automatically appear in TensorBoard.