# Unable to load images for eval in tensorflow official resnet model

Tags: tensorflow, resnet

I'm trying to train the Tensorflow official resnet model ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet)) on my own images and labels.
I created a copy of `imagenet_main.py` (`my_data_main.py`) where I changed the hard-coded values related to the dataset like so (I'm just trying to make it work with very few images at the moment):

```
"""Runs a ResNet model on the ImageNet dataset."""                             

  from __future__ import absolute_import                                         
  from __future__ import division                                                
  from __future__ import print_function                                          

  import os                                                                      
  import sys                                                                     

  import tensorflow as tf  # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order                  

  from official.resnet import imagenet_preprocessing                             
  from official.resnet import resnet_model                                       
  from official.resnet import resnet_run_loop                                    

  _DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE = 299                                                      
  _NUM_CHANNELS = 3                                                              
  _NUM_CLASSES = 9                                                               

  # TODO: generate dynamically:                                                  
  _NUM_IMAGES = {                                                                
      'train': 484,                                                              
      'validation': 121,                                                         
  }                                                                                 

  _NUM_TRAIN_FILES = 2                                                              
  _NUM_VAL_FILES = 2                                                                
  _SHUFFLE_BUFFER = 200                            

###############################################################################
# Data processing                                                                 
###############################################################################
  def get_filenames(is_training, data_dir):                                         
      """Return filenames for dataset."""                                           
      if is_training:                                                               
          return [                                                               
            os.path.join(data_dir, 'my_data_train_%05d-of-%05d.tfrecord' % (i, _NUM_TRAIN_FILES))
                for i in range(_NUM_TRAIN_FILES)]                                  
      else:                                                                      
          return [                                                               
            os.path.join(data_dir, 'my_data_validation_%05d-of-%05d.tfrecord' % (i, _NUM_VAL_FILES))
                for i in range(_NUM_VAL_FILES)] 

# rest of program unchanged
```

To load my data I created TFRecords for train and eval that I added to the data_dir directory `~/Projects/my_data/data/images/`.
I then launch the program with:

```
python3 my_data_main.py \
--data_dir ~/Projects/my_data/data/images/ \
--model_dir /tmp/tests \
--export_dir /tmp/exports \
--train_epochs 10 \
--max_train_steps 200 \
--epochs_between_evals 1 \
--batch_size 256 \
--multi_gpu \
--hooks LoggingTensorHook \
--num_parallel_calls 12  \
--inter_op_parallelism_threads 0 \
--intra_op_parallelism_threads 0 \
--dtype fp32 \
--export_dir /tmp/resnet \
--version 1 \
--resnet_size 18
```

**Problem**: the images are loaded correctly for the training but not for the evaluation. The following line in `resnet_run_loop.py` at the beginning of `def resnet_model_fn` loads the images in Tensorboard:

```
  # Generate a summary node for the images                                      
  tf.summary.image('images', features, max_outputs=6)
```

I can see my images for the train run 
[image]
but not for eval in Tensorboard
[image]

**What I checked**:
I checked that my TFRecords are read successfully.
I looked into [estimator.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/fa9d8aab41249cfc901338dfcb38cedb7ed1e603/tensorflow/python/training/evaluation.py) and printed the tensor shape from `_get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn` (called in `_evaluate_model`). I couldn't find anything wrong.

**What I haven't done yet**:
I'm currently downloading the full imagenet data to try to find a difference in the way they prep the data.

I tried my best to find answers online before I wrote this. Appreciate everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered by @robieta [on the github thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4167#issuecomment-387146286). Copying the answer here for future reference:

> I will admit this one threw me. It looks like this is an active feature request in TensorFlow. (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15332) It is possible to hack it in using hooks. ([Tensorflow Estimator API save image summary in eval mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46852018/tensorflow-estimator-api-save-image-summary-in-eval-mode)) Just note martinwicke's warnings about what a summary is in eval. Here is a simple example:

```
import tensorflow as tf


def input_fn(*args, **kwargs):
  batch_size = 20
  images = tf.zeros((batch_size, 10), tf.float32)
  labels = tf.zeros((batch_size, 1), tf.int32)
  return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((images, labels)).repeat(10)

def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
  pred = tf.layers.dense(inputs=features, units=1)

  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    loss = tf.losses.absolute_difference(labels, pred)
    tf.summary.scalar(name="train_scalar", tensor=1)
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN,
        loss=loss,
        train_op=optimizer.minimize(loss, tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()))
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
    loss = tf.losses.absolute_difference(labels, pred)
    tf.summary.scalar(name="eval_scalar", tensor=2)

    # Use a hook to force evaluation. If commented out the scalar will not be saved.
    eval_summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(
        save_steps=1,
        output_dir= "/tmp/summary_test/eval_core",
        summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all())

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL,
        loss=loss,
        evaluation_hooks=[eval_summary_hook]
    )


def main(_):
  model_dir = "/tmp/summary_test"
  if tf.gfile.Exists(model_dir):
    tf.gfile.DeleteRecursively(model_dir)

  run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_summary_steps=1)

  estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=model_fn,
      model_dir=model_dir,
      params={},
      config=run_config
  )

  for _ in range(10):
    estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn)
    estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main([])
```

> Hope this helps, and once evaluate has better support for summaries I will definitely look to save more evaluation info by default.